# How to get widgetID and ComponentName of my application in service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast, appwidgetprovider

I am updating the widget from service(srvice and widget class are in two different package) like this

```
AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(this,MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);
Intent update = new Intent();
update.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds);
 update.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
sendBroadcast(update);
```

it updates my widget but the problem is that it also updating other widgets of the device too because of which my widget updates after all the widget gets updated.

So now I want to update only my widget how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

According Android documentation `getAppWidgetIds` return a list of id that have been bound to specific `WidgetProvider`, that is all your widget instance id not id of widgets under other `WidgetProvider`.

Comment: so what is the solution ,i am stuck

Comment: when you call `getAppWidgetIds` only id that correspond to your widgets are returned and no widget of other `WidgetProvider`. so the intent of update widgets is on your widgets instances.